# Difference between DataFrame.plot.line and scatter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

What is the difference between a "line" plot and a "scatter" plot when using `DataFrame` methods `plot.line()` and `plot.scatter()`?

Obviously there are some superficial differences such as line plots being connected by default, but you could turn that off with `linestyle='none'`.

Answer (score 1):

From the document

[`DataFrame.plot.scatter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) : have parameters `s` and `c` , which can change the size and color of the point